# Is there any way to make iOS device play sound signal in a buffer continuously in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working with Swift's `AVFoundation` to launch ultrasonic sinewave and my approach is to play a .wav file. I wonder if there's approach to play the sound continuously instead of using a extra `.wav` file.

Here follows my code but I don't think the new code will be similar to this:

```
let myThread = Thread(target: self,
                          selector: #selector(ZouViewController.play()),
                          object: nil)
myThread.start()

[...]

func play(){ 
    //rewrite soom

    let fileName = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "19kHz", ofType: "wav")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName!)

    soundPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    while true{
    soundPlayer?.play()
    }

}
```

The file `19kHz.wav` is a sound file playing ultrasonic sinewave at frequency 19kHz, but its duration is not unavoidable. so there would be a  sudden change at the begin of sound signal every loop when it is played again. So I want to abandon that approach and try to play the data continuously from a buffer. Is there any way to play a sound signal in a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed it by following code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class PlaySineWave{
    var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    var audioFormat : AVAudioFormat
    let FL: AVAudioFrameCount = 44100
    let freq : Float = 19000 //19kHz

    var pcmBuffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer

    init()  {

        self.audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 44100.0, channels: 1)

        self.pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat,
                                          frameCapacity:AVAudioFrameCount(FL))
        self.pcmBuffer.frameLength = AVAudioFrameCount(FL)
    }

    func play(){
        let floatData = self.pcmBuffer.floatChannelData!.pointee
        let step = 2 * Float.pi/Float(FL)

        for i in 0 ..< Int(FL) {

            floatData[i] = 0.3 * sinf(freq * Float(i) * step)                

        }

        let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

        self.audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
        audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode,format: pcmBuffer.format)

        do {

            try audioEngine.start()

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Oh, no!  \(err.code) \(err.domain)")
        }

        playerNode.play()
        playerNode.scheduleBuffer(pcmBuffer, at:nil, options: [.loops]) { }

        //audioEngine.stop()
    }
}
```

After defined the class, In the ViewController it was called as

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        [...]

        let myThread = 

        Thread(target:self,selector:#selector(SpectralViewController.play),
object:nil)
        myThread.start()

    }

[...]

func play(){

        var Player = PlaySineWave()
        Player.play()

    }
```